# Filter observations with a string variable as date in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am looking for the right syntax to use where clause to filter a string variable as date. For example, I would like to retain records with pol_expi_dt after July 01, 2020.
pol_expi_dt takes the format of '2020-12-01 00:00:00'.
What would be the right format for this Spark Sql query?

The following code returned 0 observations. So I figure I must did something wrong

```
SELECT *
  FROM `cloud01_propertylocationmerge`.`exposure_new`
  where cast(pol_expi_dt as date) >= '2020-07-01'
```

Comment: `date(pol_expi_dt)`

Answer (score 0):

Since your `'2020-07-01'` is a string and `pol_expi_dt` is a timestamp, one should cast in the other format. For example when you cast the column,

```
date_format(pol_expi_dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd') >= '2020-07-01'
```

or cast both to the date format.

```
date(pol_expi_dt) >= date('2020-07-01')
```

Comment: you mean `date_format` instead of `format_timestamp`